# Wordpress Comments Transparent Background

Tags: css, wordpress, background-color

I just began work on this site for a client, the site is www.kingcharltonmusic.com. It was built by someone else, so maybe I just can't find what I'm looking for.

Essentially, the comment section at the end of some pages (About for example) have a transparent background, and no matter how much I alter the css it doesn't seem to effect it.

I'm not sure if I need more information than this, but if so please let me know.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on what order the rules are in, background: can override background-color.

I made a little demonstration so you can get a feel for how the various rules override each other, you can play with it:

http://jsbin.com/ecohuk/edit#html,live

You need to find out if there is another rule further down in your stylesheet that is overriding it, or at the very least use background: instead of background-color

Comment: That was it! There was a rule further down that was overriding it. Took forever to find it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Just from a quick glance, div#comments doesn't appear to have a background set explicitly. Through firebug/webkit tools I could successfully change the background to white, so I suspect that all you need is the right element to target with your css.

[image]

Comment: I thought the same thing, but when I go to the style sheet (style6.css) and add this:#comments{
background-color:#ffffff;
} It doesn't seem to take the change

Comment: "Doesn't seem to take the change" could mean any number of things, have you tried to debug what's happening with firebug/inspector?

Answer (score 1):

```
#comments {
  background-color: white;
  padding: 0.75em;
}
```

Make sure to clear your cache (server and client side) after you have uploaded your new CSS file.